# Не работает переход на другой вопрос в тесте C#

Tags: c#

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (selected_response == correct_answers_number) correct_answers = correct_answers + 1;
        if(selected_response != correct_answers_number)
        {
            wrong_answers = wrong_answers + 1;
            array[wrong_answers] = label1.Text;
        }

        if (button2.Text == "қайтадан тесті бастау")
        {
            button2.Text = "келесі сұрақ";

            radioButton1.Visible = true;
            radioButton2.Visible = true;
            radioButton3.Visible = true;
            Start(); 
            return;
        }

        if (button2.Text == "аяқтау")
        {
            Read.Close();

            radioButton1.Visible = false;
            radioButton2.Visible = false;
            radioButton3.Visible = false;

            label1.Text = String.Format("Тестілеу аяқталды.\n" +
                "дұрыс жауап: {0} из {1}.\n" +
                "жиналған ұпай: {2:F2}.", correct_answers,
                quection_count, (correct_answers * 5.0F) / quection_count);

            button2.Text = "қайтадан бастау";

            var Str = "Тізім " +
                    ":\n\n";
            for (int i = 1; i <= wrong_answers; i++)
                Str = Str + array[i] + "\n";

            if (wrong_answers != 0) MessageBox.Show(
                                                    Str, "Тестілеу аяқталды");
            
        }
        if (button2.Text == "келесі сұрақ") Вопрос();

    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас return в третьем if мешает.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (selected_response == correct_answers_number) 
        correct_answers++;
    else
    {
        wrong_answers++;
        array[wrong_answers] = label1.Text;
    }
    Button2Check();
}

private void Button2Check()
{
    if (button2.Text == "қайтадан тесті бастау")
    {
        button2.Text = "келесі сұрақ";
        RadioButtonsViseble(true);
        Start(); 
    }
    else if (button2.Text == "аяқтау")
    {
        Read.Close();
        RadioButtonsViseble(false);
        button2.Text = "қайтадан бастау";
        label1.Text = String.Format("Тестілеу аяқталды.\n" + 
            "дұрыс жауап: {0} из {1}.\n" + "жиналған ұпай: {2:F2}.", 
            correct_answers, quection_count, 
            (correct_answers * 5.0F) / quection_count);
        ShowWrongAnswers();     
    }
    else if (button2.Text == "келесі сұрақ")
        Вопрос();    //Используйте английские наименования
}

private void RadioButtonsViseble(bool IsVisible)
{
    radioButton1.Visible = IsVisible;
    radioButton2.Visible = IsVisible;
    radioButton3.Visible = IsVisible;
}

private void ShowWrongAnswers()
{
    if (wrong_answers == 0) return; 
    var Str = "Тізім :\n\n";
    for (int i = 1; i <= wrong_answers; i++)
       Str = Str + array[i] + "\n";
    MessageBox.Show(Str, "Тестілеу аяқталды");  
}
```